# laptop two public IP addresses

Tags: ip

My computer shows two different public IP addresses at two different location. Is it not suppose to show one address as my laptop is registered with Home agent (router at my home) and when visits the foreign network it is assigned temporary IP address but the main IP address should be the one assigned by HA?

Comment: Home agent? I have never seen anyone use Mobile IP in practice, and I don't think any OSes even support it fully... Can you demonstrate where the OS shows the home-agent registration, and where you're checking the public IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer normally "negotiates" what address it will have with the router it is communicating with. On some networks, like your home network, you can set up what is formally called a "DHCP Reservation", which ensures that *on that network* you will always get the same IP address. However, when you are not connected to that network, the reservation does not apply, and you will get whatever address the network finds available for you.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. Your assumption isn't true.

The computer only has one Public IP address and that is the one assigned by the router it is connected at that moment.

Comment: It would actually be more accurate to say the address assigned by the DHCP (or PPP) of the network to which it is connected. DHCP is not really a router function, but a DHCP server is often included in a home networking router chassis.

Comment: A computer can have any number of public IP addresses, even on a single network interface. Not everyone is subject to NAT.